# GUI Calculator using JFrames and layouts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, grid-layout

I'm currently working on a calculator which should perform basic calculations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. To achieve the final outcome, I've to follow a certain design for the calculator. The design of the calculator is provided with this question. I've given my best on how to match the official design of the calculator but it's not matching it.

This is the OFFICIAL design of the calculator. This is how it should look.

[image]

This is WHAT I'm getting when I run the code.

[image]

The CODE:

```
    package patel.Jainam;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * All the buttons that will be used in the calculator have been initialized 
     */
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2; 
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JButton button6; 
    private JButton button7;
    private JButton button8;
    private JButton button9;
    private JButton button0; 

    private JButton buttonEqual;
    private JButton buttonDot;

    private JButton buttonClearLast;
    private JButton buttonClearAll;

    private JButton buttonAdd;
    private JButton buttonSub;
    private JButton buttonMul;
    private JButton buttonDiv;

    private JTextArea textArea; 


    public CalculatorFrame(){

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();       
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    panel2.add(buttonClearLast = new JButton ("Clear Last"));
    panel2.add(buttonClearAll = new JButton ("Clear All"));
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    textArea = new JTextArea(2,10);
//  textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel3.add(scrollPane);
    add(panel3, BorderLayout.LINE_START);



    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));      

    panel1.add(button7 = new JButton ("7"));
    panel1.add(button8 = new JButton ("8"));
    panel1.add(button9 = new JButton ("9"));
    panel1.add(buttonAdd = new JButton ("+"));
    panel1.add(button4 = new JButton ("4"));
    panel1.add(button5 = new JButton ("5"));
    panel1.add(button6 = new JButton ("6"));
    panel1.add(buttonSub = new JButton ("-"));
    panel1.add(button1 = new JButton ("1"));
    panel1.add(button2 = new JButton ("2"));
    panel1.add(button3 = new JButton ("3"));
    panel1.add(buttonMul = new JButton ("*"));
    panel1.add(button0 = new JButton ("0"));
    panel1.add(buttonDot = new JButton ("."));
    panel1.add(buttonEqual = new JButton ("="));
    panel1.add(buttonDiv = new JButton ("/"));

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are over using the GridLayout.

I would suggest you want to keep using the default layout manager of the frame which is a `BorderLayout`.

Then you would do the following:

1. Create a panel using a `GridLayout` for the two buttons. Add this panel to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` of the frame.
2. Add your scroll pane containing the text area to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the frame.
3. Create a panel using the `GridLayout` for the buttons on the bottom. Add this panel to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` of the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples of the `Borderlayout` and `GridLayout`.

Comment: so I tried what u told me to and came up with the following code. It still doesn't match the design. The code has been updated.

Comment: I said that  you  were overusing the GridLayout. Why did you create a panel "p" with a GridLayout?.  I suggested (3 times) that you add the components to the frame (not the panel), using the BorderLayout constraint. Get rid of the panel you called "p". Also, I suggested you should be adding the scroll pane directly to the frame, not to a panel first. Take the time to read the tutorial and understand how the layout managers work. Then think logically about breaking down your layout to take advantage of the layout features of different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: Okay so I was able to match the design but the TextArea is not setting up properly with the frame along with the JScroll Pane. I've updated the code and the image also. Thank you.

Comment: @Jpatel Why do I have to keep repeating myself?. I have already told you the scroll pane should be added to the frame. Why are you creating extra components??? Did you not read the tutorial yet? It explains how the BorderLayout works.

Answer (score 0):

camickr's answer is optimal here.

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame {

    public CalculatorFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(createClearPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(createNumberPanels(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setSize(300, 300);
        pack();
    }

    private JPanel createNumberPanels() {
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("" + i);
            main.add(button);
        }
        return main;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(5, 10);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(area);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        return sp;
    }

    private JPanel createClearPanel() {
        JButton clearAll = new JButton("clear all");
        JButton clearLast = new JButton("Clear last");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        panel.add(clearLast);
        panel.add(clearAll);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CalculatorFrame().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: Preview]

P.S: Ignore the fact i used only numbers instead of operators like *,?,+,= etc.

Comment: Thank you so much the help.

Comment: @J patel No problem. camickr had already help you. I just did the SSCCE, after i saw you still having problem to get to the point.

Comment: 1) there is no need to set the layout for the content pane. The default layout is the BorderLayout as I stated in my answer. 2) there is no need to use getContentPane(). When you add a component to the frame it will be added to the content pane for you. 3) When you create a text area you should use `new JTextArea(5, 10)` to suggest the row/columns of the text area so the text area can calculate its preferred size. 4) use pack() so the frame can be sized at its preferred size.

Comment: @camickr 1) I always prefer to have the layout of the container in front of my eyes. Plus, this question is all about border layout. 2) Before java 1.5 (i think) you had to use ContentPane, it is just habbit i have inherited from old docs/tutorials. 3) & 4) Editing right now, i thought i pack(), which would show me the cols & rows of the textarea. Thanks for noticing :)